# Spring Integration Http OutboundGateway PUT with header parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am trying to make a PUT on a remote REST endpoint for which I need to provide the credentials as part of the headers without success so far.

Approach 1:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow outboundGateway() {
        return flow -> flow
                .transform(transformer)
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("x-api-key", "secret123")
                                     .header("contentType", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .handle(Http.outboundGateway("https://remote-service.com/car")
                        .mappedRequestHeaders()
                .httpMethod(HttpMethod.PUT)
                .expectedResponseType(String.class))
                .log();
    }
```

I keep getting a 403 Forbidden.

I achieved the same with a RestTemplate so easily:

```
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(getHeaders());
restTemplate.put("https://remote-service.com/car", request);
...

    private HttpHeaders getHeaders() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("x-api-key", "secret123");
        return headers;
    }
```

How can I send this x-api-key header and its value with the Http OutboundGateway?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `x-api-key`is not a standard http header, so you need to make it to be transferred:

```
 .mappedRequestHeaders(*)
```

For your `Http.outboundGateway()`.

See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/http.html#http-header-mapping